# Which frameworks can be used with PMBoK?

Tags: pmbok

Which frameworks can be used with PMBoK? Which frameworks are related with PMBoK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PMBoK **is** the framework - it's akin (but different) to PRINCE2 or Agile.

PMBoK is, obviously, much more Project Manager focused than the other frameworks. You can use pieces of the PMBoK framework with pieces of the PRINCE2 framework and/or pieces of the Agile frameworks. You don't have to be "all in" for any of them. Most PMs will subscribe to one core framework but use pieces from many more.